# onScroll event is not firing for listview

Tags: android

I am developing an app where I need to show some list view control. I am just implementing the `OnScrollListener` in my activity in order to monitor my listview content but it's not invoking the onScroll event when I set the layout for my activity. If i comment that block then it invokes it just fine. How do I solve this issue?

```
package com.Threadtest;

import com.Threadtest.main.myRunnable;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;

public class TestList extends ListActivity implements OnScrollListener {

    Aleph0 adapter = new Aleph0();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        ListView listview=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        /*setListAdapter(adapter); 
        getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);*/
    }

    public void onScroll(AbsListView view,
        int firstVisible, final int visibleCount, int totalCount) {

        Log.i("TestList", "firstVisible="+firstVisible+" visibleCount="+visibleCount+" totalCount="+totalCount);
        boolean loadMore = /* maybe add a padding */
            firstVisible + visibleCount >= totalCount;

        if(loadMore) {
            Log.i("TestList", "In Notify");
            Thread thread = new Thread()
            {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                      try {
                        this.sleep(10000);
                        runOnUiThread(new myRunnable(adapter,visibleCount));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                  }
              };

            thread.start();

        }
    }

    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView v, int s) { } 

    class myRunnable implements Runnable
    {
        Aleph0 adapter;

        public myRunnable(Aleph0 adapter,int visibleCount)
        {

            this.adapter=adapter;
            this.adapter.count += visibleCount;
        }
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Log.i("TestList", "List Count="+adapter.count);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

    class Aleph0 extends BaseAdapter {
        int count = 40; /* starting amount */

        public int getCount() { return count; }
        public Object getItem(int pos) { return pos; }
        public long getItemId(int pos) { return pos; }

        public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup p) {
            if(pos!=count-1)
            {
                TextView view = new TextView(TestList.this);
                view.setText("entry " + pos);
                return view;
            }
            TextView view = new TextView(TestList.this);
            view.setText("Loading.. " + pos);
            return view;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. Did you mean to say that if you omit `getListView().setOnScrollListener(this)`, it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes. If a Ommit the getListView().setOnScrollListener(this) It's Not getting fired.

Comment: Right, if you omit listener, it will not fire. What is there real problem, **you want to fire without setting listener?!**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`getListView().setOnScrollListener(this)` is necessary to bind the listener to the `ListView`. The `ListActivity` class does not provide an "automatic" way of binding most of the listeners, It only provides an automatic way of binding the `OnItemClickListener`. Check out the [ListActivity code](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:u70Jb8D8qEMJ:www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ListActivity.java%20listactivity.java&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com).

Answer (score 1):

If you change your onScroll signature to `public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisible, int visibleCount, int totalCount)` will it be called? By adding the `final` qualifier, you've changed the method signature and this will cause your overridden method to not be seen. Copy the visibleCount int to a new (final) int so you can access it in your thread.

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.test); 

        ListView listview=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list); 
        listview.setAdapter(adapter); 
        listview.setOnScrollListener(onLstScroll);    
} 


OnScrollListener onLstScroll= new OnScrollListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
   {
       //Do something
   }

   @Override
   public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)
   {
      //Do something
   }
};
```

Answer (score -4):

You're missing the `@Override` notation on the `onScroll()` and `onScrollStateChanged()` methods.

Comment: @Override doesn't get compiled into byte code. It just states that you *intended* to override something, so the compiler can tell you if you didn't.

Comment: @dmon Please see this question to see why it's required in order for the method to be called (relates to Android and Activities) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950074/android-override-usage

Comment: Maybe *you* should re-read that answer, which states exactly what I commented on your answer.

Comment: @dmon -- if the OP included the @Override notation, the compiler would have told him that in fact he's not overriding a method, because he changed the original method's signature by adding the final qualifier. Andre's answer is valid and helpful, even if not explicitly explaining why.

Comment: @mah the final is not the problem. `OnScrollListener` is an interface, the code would not compile *at all* if he was not properly overriding the methods.