# AndroId MediaPlayer prepareAsync method

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-mediaplayer, prepare

I have a strange problem. I use the prepareAsync method with the `MediaPlayer`, but the listener that I declared just never gets fired. I try to stream a live `.mp3` feed from the Internet (radio station). I use an inline method for the listener, but I also tried implementing the interface without any success. Here's a portion of my code :

**In the member section :**

```
String url = "http://<my_url>.mp3";
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

**In Activity `onCreate()` :**

```
ToggleButton playButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.playToggleButton);
playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
playButton.clearFocus();
playButton.setClickable(false);

mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        ToggleButton playButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.playToggleButton);
        playButton.setClickable(true);
        mp.start();
    }
});

preparePlayer();
```

**Then, here's the `preparePlayer()` method :**

```
private void preparePlayer() {
    if (mediaPlayer == null) {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    }
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Toast.makeText(
                MyStreamActivity.this,
                getResources().getString(R.string.erreurIllegalArgument),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Toast.makeText(
                MyStreamActivity.this,
                getResources().getString(R.string.erreurIllegalState),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(
                MyStreamActivity.this,
                getResources().getString(R.string.erreurIO),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**And (just for the record), the `onDetroy()` where I do the cleaning :**

```
private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
}
```

Comment: does the log say anything about what happens or are there errors? Do you have the permission to internets?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are setting the `OnPreparedListener` in your `Activity`'s create method and later on, possibly, creating a new `MediaPlayer` in your `preparePlayer()` method.  Any newly created `MediaPlayer`'s wont have the `prepareListener` set. You should also add an `errorlistener` to find out whats going on.

You may want to move the `setOnPreparedListener` call inside the

```
  if (mediaPlayer == null) {
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
}
```

as well as setting a `setOnErrorListener` like so:

```
if (mediaPlayer == null) {
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(....);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            ToggleButton playButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.playToggleButton);
            playButton.setClickable(true);
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Please change `e.printStackTrace();` to

```
Log.e("tag", e.getMessage(), e);
```

Hope this helps, let us know if you have any log data as this will also be useful.

Comment: Thanks ! I used your advice ans check if it's null before. But that didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks! Very well explained

Answer (score 2):

Turned out, I forgot to mention the "@Override" on top of my inner method. Like this :

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        ToggleButton playButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.playToggleButton);
        playButton.setClickable(true);
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

Now everything works fine. Well... almost, since it takes forever to buffer...

Comment: quite old, but I'd still like to point out that *the @Override statement doesn't produce code* and therefore can't possibly be a solution to this or other code-related issues. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8545586/2177061 for reference.

Comment: That probably isn't the cause of this problem. I'm now having the exact same problem and setting "Override" doesn't help. While the example application also didn't set it anyways.

Comment: `@Override` is totally optional in Java, whether Android or Swing or Java EE. Thus this cannot never be your problem