# how work mp3 steaming from Url

Tags: android

```
  private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
  mp.reset();                       
  mp.setDataSource("http://thesixteendigital.com.s3.amazonaws.com/testfiles/Hallelujah.mp3");
  mp.prepare();
  mp.start();
```

I am following this code .But not working
[image]

Comment: did you add internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: yes<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307131/android-mediaplayer-prepareasync-method) - the question plus the accepted answer will give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

For streaming you want to `prepareAsync()` instead of prepare

```
     public class MusicPlayer implements OnPreparedListener //, OnErrorListener , OnCompletionListener
     {

        private MediaPlayer mp;
        public MusicPlayer()
        {
             mp = new MediaPlayer();
             mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
             mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        }
        public void play()
        {
              mp.reset();                       
              mp.setDataSource("http://thesixteendigital.com.s3.amazonaws.com/testfiles/Hallelujah.mp3");
              mp.prepareAsync();
        }
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0)//
        {
            mp.start();
        }
}
```

You need to implement  `OnErrorListener , OnCompletionListener` on later stage

Comment: I believe this isn't strictly true. (1) Streaming does work with sync (just not the best thing to do); (2) with async you need to start AFTER the prepare is complete - you need to use `onPreparedListener` on the mediaplayer.

Comment: am try this codes also, but same error coming, am testing in emulator

Comment: yes you are right you just need the onPreparedListener and it will work, ill update my code

Answer (score 0):

set Internet permission in your AndoridManifest.xml file

```
String url = "http://thesixteendigital.com.s3.amazonaws.com/testfiles/Hallelujah.mp3"; // your URL here
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        try{
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
        mediaPlayer.start();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IllegalStateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: sorry I didn't get you could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

**Use this..**

```
String url = "http://........"; // your URL here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Also use the **INTERNET** Permission in your Manifest.

Comment: yups.. follow the link

Answer (score 0):

```
private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();                    
  mp.setDataSource("http://thesixteendigital.com.s3.amazonaws.com/testfiles/Hallelujah.mp3");
  mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();

            }
        });
```