# Passing custom parameters to a parent activity through onCreate method yields confusing linter error

Tags: java, android, inheritance, overriding, oncreate

Why does passing custom parameters to a parent activity through an onCreate method, while leaving overriding the root method to the parent, result in the following linter error:

> Overriding method should call super.onCreate

### Background

For example, I have a MainActivity class that extends from ParentActivity that extends Android's Activity.

[image: example inheritance]

[UML Generator](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/SoWkIImgAStDuN9CBiaiooofLD3LLGX8B4hDAu69SC6u20M-YPbvS6dddCJYOWMuT3LNBLG8eWzJ0gOT8UoGcfS2T0G0)

In order to make my app more abstract I am trying to handle several things in ParentActivity that the developer need not see in their development and use of MainActivity.

I have several parameters I would like to pass to the ParentActivity, like booleans turning on and off log functionalities, but it seems passing them through the onCreate() method is not ~~possible~~ recommended since this throws linter errors. I will make a separate question regarding the best practices for passing such parameters upward to custom parent classes using custom methods or directly setting parent fields, but I was looking to verify my current understanding of why this is not ~~possible~~ recommended through the existing onCreate method and additional parameters.

### What has been tried

As a starting point, if I have some basic MainActivity and ParentActivity:

#### Code 0.1

```
public class MainActivity extends ParentActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Do stuff
    }
}
public class ParentActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

and then try to add further parameters to onCreate, e.g. a boolean to turn on/off some logger functionality within ParentActivity:

#### Code 0.2

```
public class MainActivity extends ParentActivity{
    boolean logOn = true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, logOn);
        //Do stuff
    }
}
public class ParentActivity extends Activity{
    // No longer overriding Activity.onCreate() due to diff in params
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, boolean logOn){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Android Studio first warns me that I am not overriding the parent's method, which makes sense as it has a different parameter count, but then I thought I can just remove the `@Override` and call it good since I'm still calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` in ParentActivity, which will pass the savedInstanceState up to Activity, and I'm still passing the savedInstanceState to ParentActivity from MainActivity. At this point I encountered my first unknown issue: back in MainActivity, I get a linter error that states

> Overriding method should call super.onCreate

Whats confusing is that I do call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, logOn)` directly below where I get this error.  Although the error message is not too informative, I can get rid of the error by calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` directly above the already existing call to `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, logOn)`, i.e.:

#### Code 0.3

```
public class MainActivity extends ParentActivity{
    boolean logOn = true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, logOn);
        //Do stuff
    }
}
public class ParentActivity extends Activity{
    // No longer overriding Activity.onCreate() due to diff in params
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, boolean logOn){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Looking at the tooltip inline doc using Android Studio, I see that `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` is calling the onCreate method from Activity (i.e the parent class of ParentClass) and `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, logOn);` is calling the onCreate method of ParentClass. With typical inheritance in mind, and matching parameter lengths and types, this makes sense.

What doesn't make sense to me is why I have to call the onCreate method of Activity in MainActivity. Why does the call to onCreate within ParentActivity not suffice? i.e. why does Code 0.2 throw the linter error:

> Overriding method should call super.onCreate

? I note, as per the comment by @[greeble31](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6759241/greeble31) that Code 0.2 compiles, and runs on my example smartphone, but the linter error remains.

Comment: @greeble31, yes you are right, I updated the question to correct the wording from compiler to linter. I will work on rewriting the question and title to better include this difference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's too much to worry about, since the problem is limited to a lint warning. You just did something a little too complicated for the linter to follow; your program is not, in fact, incorrect.

You could suppress the warning (`@SupressLint`), or simply ignore it.

> ...I can just remove the `@Override` and call it good...

Not too sure I agree with you, there... Removing the `@Override` annotation can't really help anything; the linter/compiler still knows what's an override and what's not. I consider the annotation useful b/c the IDE will tell you if you *think* you're overriding a method, but you're actually not, i.e. due to a signature mismatch or something (as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2950161/6759241)).

**SUGGESTED APPROACH**

FWIW, I would've solved this problem a little differently. (Note that code 0.3 actually results in *two* calls to the base class `onCreate()`; that's probably illegal.) I would just change the method name (to reflect a semantic distinction between configuration and creation), and store some state information in the base class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ParentActivity{
    boolean logOn = true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        configure(logOn);    //Required, per base class specification
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Do stuff
    }
}
public abstract class ParentActivity extends Activity{

    boolean logOn;
    boolean configured = false;

    /** Subclasses are obligated to call this before calling super.onCreate() */
    protected void configure(boolean logOn)
    {
        this.logOn = logOn;
        this.configured = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        if(!configured)
            throw new IllegalStateException("configure() not called prior to onCreate()");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Do stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        configured = false;    //(just being pedantic)
    }
}
```

It's really just a matter of taste.

Sometimes people don't realize that Android can spontaneously create Activities on its own, like when it restores the back-stack state of your app. (This is why you want to be able to serialize and deserialize your `Activity` state to/from the bundle; b/c your `Activity` might not be re-created using the same workflow that caused its creation the first time).

I don't think that's going to be an issue for you, though, since `ParentActivity` (which I've declared as `abstract`) is always going to be instantiated via a concrete subclass, and all subclasses are guaranteed to call `configure()` in their `onCreate()` methods. (IOW, `ParentActivity` wouldn't have a manifest entry, so the system is never going to try to instantiate a base-class `ParentActivity` by itself.)

Just something to be aware of. (You had `logOn` set to a constant value in `MainActivity`, so if you were planning on changing that dynamically based on the app state, before calling `configure()/super.onCreate()`, just bear in mind that -- if you don't take steps to prevent it -- that information could be lost when your app is restored to the foreground.)

Comment: The comment regarding the removal of the @Override call was not an attempt to fool the linter, but more to point out that I was no longer overriding ParentActivity's method, but rather Activitiy's. I suppose that is not really correct either though :/.

Comment: Yes, your solution is what I was leaning towards as well, and what I was hinting at when I said I'd "make a separate question regarding the best practices for passing such parameters upward to custom parent classes using custom methods" I was just concerned with tidiness really, as I didn't want it to end up looking something like onCreate() followed by onCreate2()...Exaggeratedly bad naming there, but you get the point I guess.

Comment: Nope, the logOn was just something to be set for debug builds only. Thanks for the tips though!

Answer (score 0):

IDE will check `@CallSuper` **annotation** when on compilation `{@link Activity#onCreate}`.

Comment: Mind clarifying how this solves the problem illustrated by my question?